# NodeJs Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to nodejs and stuck up with this **Error:Can't set headers after they are sent.** Below is my code. Please help. I used postman to test this code. It is working for the first 2 hits but on the 3rd hit this error is coming.

```
const http = require('http');

const fs = require('fs')

module.exports.verifyPyeval5 = function(request, response){
    let filePath = "D:/PyEval/NewPyEvalRequests/solution.txt";  
    fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
       var json = JSON.parse(data);
        post_call(json,function(res){
            response.status(200)
        .json(res);
        });
    });   

};

var post_call = function(new_val,callback){
    var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) { 
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            callback(chunk);
        });
      });
      post_req.write(JSON.stringify(new_val));
      post_req.end();

};

var post_options = {
      host: 'acclabserv',
      port: '8080',
      path: '/generate',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
  };
```

Comment: why are you using this line `post_req.write(JSON.stringify(new_val));` what it is for ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

Comment: **post_req.write(JSON.stringify(new_val));** This is for writing a json to the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it the issue is with callback function it gets called more then once.

```
var post_call = function(new_val,callback){
    var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(res) { 
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        var str = null;
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
        });
      res.on('end', function () {
            callback(str);
        });
      });
      post_req.write(JSON.stringify(new_val));
      post_req.end();

};
```

One more thing to note here I dont know the type of chuck if its an object and you want array of object in response then you can use this

> var str = []; //in req.on('data') str.push(chunck)

Comment: I have used status and send in chain only.

Comment: Updated my answer yes you have used it in chain but there is no need and check the answer.

Comment: I tried by removing status. but issue persists. I am not able to find where callback is getting called twice. can you please help?

Comment: req.on('data') this gets called many time use terminating callback like req.on('end')

Comment: Thanks for help. I will check the solution and update accordingly.

Comment: OP has modularized the code keep the way it is. don't try to remove the function and keep in main. Its not a good practice anyway. @YashGanatra

Comment: sorry I didn't get you @ArpitSolanki

Comment: Oh yes, You are right @ArpitSolanki I was just giving the example not trying to change his structure

Comment: Its better for the readers if you keep the structure as it. Example is ok but if you point out the problem without changing the structure then it would be nice

Comment: I will keep that in mind. I haven't done it though. As I just replaced status.json to send and updated the end callback there's nothing to deal with modularization.

Comment: btw the web service is giving exact same response every time. How is it working for first 2 times and failing 3rd time exactly.